# How can I keep products in CART when guest user Leaves the Site. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, user, guest

I want to keep the products in *Add to cart* for guest user when He leave the site how is it will be possible?? for example I'm a guest user n I add few products in *Add to cart* n then I close the browser or the site but when I reopen the site then the products which I add before already exists in *Cart* how is it will be possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does this automatically. You can adjust the cookie lifetime in the backend, which will determine how long the cart is stored - I think default is 1 hour, you can set it to 2 weeks or what you like.

When the user deletes their cookies, though, there's no way to have him keep cart items without a customer account. This is because the PHP session has, without a cookie, no way to determine who this user was.